# Send dynamically generated image as an attachment in email c#

Tags: c#, winforms, email, email-attachments

I'm creating an image in runtime.

Later on, this will be sent as an attachment. Here is my code-

```
Bitmap qr = CreateCode(false);
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
Attachment a = new Attachment(qr); //error
```

Last line shows ".... invalid arguements".

I don't want to save it locally.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I believe this takes in a stream and you can use that in the contructor of Attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the bitmap into a stream and then use the [Attachment stream constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds708xx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using(var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    Bitmap qr = CreateCode(false);
    qr.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    Attachment a = new Attachment(stream,'myBitmap.bmp',MediaTypeNames.Image.Bmp);
}
```

the constructor params are:

```
public Attachment(
    Stream contentStream,
    string name,
    string mediaType
)
```

Comment: There isnt an attachment constructor that takes only stream, should be stream and a string.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that, sorry

Comment: Its also important to keep in mind resources dispose, not doing so may lead to memory leaks

Comment: Agreed, added a using statement on the stream and place code inside of the block

Answer (score 0):

The `Attachments` property on the `MailMessage` class is a collection of `Attachment` type objects.
You can only add items of the `Attachment` type.

Take a look at the various constructors of `Attachment` to see which one best fits your need - there are two that take a `Stream` argument, so you might need to get a `MemoryStream` from you `Bitmap` and set the appropriate content type and disposition data.

Edit: You changed your code sample while I was writing this but you should still look at the various `Attachment` constructors.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a QR code image on the HTML page.
you must be sent QR code image in attachments and use the code below in the HTML body

```
byte[] image = //an image
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
var qrAttachment = new Attachment(stream, "QrImage.png");
attachments.Add(qrAttachment);
//bottom code is so important
string body = $"<img src=\"cid:{qrAttachment.ContentId}\" />";
 MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
            {
                To = { "test@test.com"},
                Body = body,
            };
 foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                {
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
 smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```